# Prevent invalid hook call when calling useContext in a functional component that renders another component?

Tags: reactjs, use-context, react-dom-server

Here is the example code:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Context } from './MainContext';
import ReactDomServer from 'react-dom/server';
//Import SomeOtherComponent
import { SomeOtherComponent} from './SomeOtherComponent';

export const SomeComponent = () => {
    const { state } = useContext(Context);
    const result = ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
    <SomeOtherComponent
        name={state.name}
        date={state.date}
    />
);
```

SomeComponent will be used in a handleSubmit function like so:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   SomeComponent({ ...state });
   setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      submitted: true,
   }));
};
```

I am getting the following error:

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such
   as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See
   fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
   and fix this problem.

I believe the issue is that I'm calling **useContext** and not returning anything. - How can this function be restructured to account for the issue and maintain usage of `ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup` on an imported component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the issue.

I was already passing state as an argument in `SomeComponent` within my `handleSubmit` function, so the best solution for me was to forego the `useContext` hook entirely and simply let `SomeComponent` accept state as an argument.

**Solution:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDomServer from 'react-dom/server';
//Import SomeOtherComponent
import { SomeOtherComponent} from './SomeOtherComponent';

export const SomeComponent = ({...state}) => {
    const result = ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
    <SomeOtherComponent
        name={state.name}
        date={state.date}
    />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`useContext` must be called inside a component. As I see `SomeComponent` is not returning anything and `result` is a ReadableStream, so I believe is an example. Try this:

```js
export const SomeComponent = () => {
    const result = ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
        () => {
             const { state } = useContext(Context);
             return <SomeOtherComponent
                name={state.name}
                date={state.date}
             />;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This is invalid. You cannot call the useContext hook inside of a callback function.

Comment: @Dr.Tenma more than a callback, is a `React.FC`

Comment: If this solution doesn't work, try to use the `<Context.Consumer> (state) => <SomeOtherComponent name={state.name} date={state.date} /></Context.Consumer>`